# dijit.form.button with img src in programmatic

Tags: image, dojo, src, dijit.form

Is there a way to add img src tag in programmatic for a dijit.form.button?

In declarative, we can do something like this :

`<div dojoType="dijit.form.Button"><img src="images/img.png"/></div>`

In this case, the dijit button is completely replace by the image.

If I try something like this, the image not replace button but appear in :

```
var button = new dijit.form.Button({
        showLabel : false,
        label : "Validate",
        iconClass : "alphaIcon validateIcon",   
    })
```

Your help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach should be to do exactly what you did AND create custom css to modify the appearance.

```
myIconButton.dijitButton .dijitButtonNode {
  border: 0;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

var button = ... // same as above
dojo.addClass(button.domNode, 'myIconButton');
```

To directly answer your question, you could create your own button widget with a custom template that only had the image source.

```
dojo.declare("MyIconButton", [Button], {
  templateString: '<div><img src="${imageSrc}"></img></div>'
});
```

NOTE: I didn't test this approach and there may be other modifications that you would need in MyIconButton because the base Button class would be expecting other nodes in the template.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I would try the second one and come give us some feedback when it's done

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what you want

```
this.button1.attr('label','<img src="' + this.constants.packagePrefix + '/images/button1.gif"/>');
```

I found it here:
http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2009-August/038353.html

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a class with background-image for buttons. This *really* made it hard to dynamically set the image. So, I had success using this:

```
domStyle.set(myButton.iconNode, 'background-image', 'url(images/icon.png)');
```

The trick was using iconNode, rather than domNode or containerNode.